# Identification of Foundry equipment

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, equipment-selection

Good day! We (undergraduates w/o prior foundry experience) inspected a foundry for its health hazards, our problem is we are not permitted to be accompanied by a laboratory assistant, so we don't have any idea what the following parts are for, kindly help us, thank you for your help! :)

(a)[image]

(b)
[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on your own as to what it might be? Also, you weren't allowed to talk to the people running the machines, but it is OK to ask the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The first picture looks like a top-loading electric kiln:
[image]

A foundry might use one to bake refractory molds prior to casting.  Not sure what the second picture is.